# Read registry showing invalid root in registry key

Tags: vbscript

I have to read registry value "GDIProcessHandleQuota" so that I have write below code

```
strKeyPath = "Schema\wcm://Microsoft-Windows-Win32k-Settings?version=6.1.7600.16385&language=neutral&processorArchitecture=x86&publicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35&versionScope=nonSxS&scope=allUsers\metadata\elements\GDIProcessHandleQuota"

Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set value = WSHShell.RegRead(strKeyPath)
```

When run this script its showing me error

> WshShell.RegRead: Invalid root in registry key "Schema\wcm://Microsoft-Windows-Win32k-Settings?version=6.1.7600.16385&language=neutral&processorArchitecture=x86&publicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35&versionScope=nonSxS&scope=allUsers\metadata\elements\GDIProcessHandleQuota".

Used WMI:

```
'Constants (taken from WinReg.h)
Const HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT= &H80000000
Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER= &H80000001
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE= &H80000002
Const HKEY_USERS= &H80000003

Set oReg = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\default:StdRegProv")

strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows"
strValueName = "GDIProcessHandleQuota"
oReg.GetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, strValueName, strValue
WScript.Echo strValue
```

Above script showing error "type mismatch".

How should read in correct way or is there any alternative way to iterate through registry and find subkey because i have hardcoded the key that have to avoid. I just want write code like pass GDIProcessHandleQuota so that code will provide value.

Comment: Your first code snippet raises an error, because the registry path is missing the hive (`HKLM`). Also you have different paths in the two code snippets, so your question is entirely unclear. Is "GDIProcessHandleQuota" a key? A value? The data in a value? Is it a REG_SZ? REG_DWORD? REG_BINARY? Where exactly is it located in the registry?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: `GDIProcessHandleQuota` is a `REG_DWORD` value in the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows` key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea what the first snippet is trying to do.  I have never seen a key path like that before.

But the second code snippet fails with a type mismatch error because `GDIProcessHandleQuota` is a `REG_DWORD` value but you are trying to read it as a `REG_SZ` value.  You need to use the [`StdRegProv.GetDWORDValue()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390445.aspx) method instead of the [`StdRegProv.GetStringValue()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390788.aspx) method.

In any case, you don't need to enumerate the keys in this situation, since the location of `GDIProcessHandleQuota` is [fixed and documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724291.aspx).